Using mypy with pandas `to_dict` method
Here is a simplified version of my actual code:
import pandas as pd
from typing import Dict

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"year": [2024, 2025], "my_output": [1, 2], "foo": ["a", "b"]}
)

df.set_index("year", inplace=True)

row_dict = df.to_dict("index")

ouput_dict: Dict[int, int] = {
    key: val["my_output"] for key, val in row_dict.items()
}

When I run mypy over this I get the following error:
Key expression in dictionary comprehension has incompatible type "Hashable"; expected type "int"
How can I tell mypy that the keys I set using the "year" column are integers?

The dataframe itself isn't statically typed, so I think the best you can do is use cast to tell mypy what row_dict is. This may or may not involve defining a TypedDict that mirrors what to_dict will (or is expected to) return.

I ran your code with no errors. what version of pandas are you using?

@chepner - prefer not to use cast. I could just cast key to int and everything will work. Seems like cheating?

@iBeMeltin - version 2.2.1, though this isn't a problem with the code not running... It's an issue with mypy complaining.

@Frank I would cast earlier, if possible. For example, define something like TypedDict('MyDataFrame', year=list[int], my_output=list[int], foo=list[str]), then row_dict = cast(MyDataFrame, df.to_dict("index")). Then all subsequent operations on row_dict should work without additional casting.

df.to_dict("index") converts your dataframe to a dictionary where the keys are of type Hashable and not necessarily int. mypy expects the keys in ouput_dict to be int. You need to assert the type of the keys.
import pandas as pd
from typing import Dict, Hashable, Any

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"year": [2024, 2025], "my_output": [1, 2], "foo": ["a", "b"]}
)

df.set_index("year", inplace=True)

row_dict = df.to_dict("index")

ouput_dict: Dict[int, int] = {
    int(key): val["my_output"] for key, val in row_dict.items() if isinstance(key, int)
}


and
print(output_dict)

{2024: 1, 2025: 2}


